# Codeigniter same input name array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I am working on this application which i need to achieve something like this, in the system we are allowing the system administrator to add customers and their vehicles,

Customers can have one or more vehicles, by default there are 8 fields to add the information of customer's vehicle i have named all the input fields as "vehicle[]"

ex: `<input type="text" name="vehicle[]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" />`

all the input fields goes by the name "vehicle[]".

[image: this is my interface]

by clicking "Add another" user will get another set of same fields (same 8 default fields ) this also has the same name of "vehicle[]".

what i want to do is insert all the vehicle information to  vehicles table in my database. columns Vehicle number to  vehicle_number  so on.

how can i handle though an array or some other method.

Comment: On form submit what data you got in array?

Comment: What about using : `vehicle[][vehicle_number]` , it will result to multi-dimenssional array in this way : `array([0]=>array('vehicle_number'=>23092093));` , and so on , on every new vehicle added , the main key will change to  : `1,2,3,4,5,6`

Comment: array should be first array <input type="text" name="vehicle[][]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" /> while add another... <input type="text" name="vehicle[][1]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" /> like this  if another one means  <input type="text" name="vehicle[][2]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" /> something like this

Comment: @jothi better to use field name as key of value as he might need to find out which information he needs.

Comment: ya that's also good idea @ArshSingh

Comment: @– Arsh Singh how can i do this

Comment: @ jothi seeme you solution is fine, i am adding fields for add another option using jquery. how can i achieve what you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Make your form like this

```
<input type="text" name="vehicle[vehicle_no][]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" />
<input type="text" name="vehicle[make][]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" />
<input type="text" name="vehicle[model][]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" />
<input type="text" name="vehicle[chassis_no][]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" />
<input type="text" name="vehicle[engine][]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" />
<input type="text" name="vehicle[color][]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" />
<input type="text" name="vehicle[type][]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" />
<input type="text" name="vehicle[battery][]" placeholder="" class="form-control name_list" />
```

so in CI you can access it like:-

```
$postedData = $this->input->post();
$objectToinsert = array()
for($postedData['vehicle']['vehicle_no'] as $key => $vehicle){
     //This is how you can get individual record
     $objectToinsert['vehicle_no'] = $postedData['vehicle']['vehicle_no'][$key];
     $objectToinsert['make'] = $postedData['vehicle']['make'][$key];
     $objectToinsert['model'] = $postedData['vehicle']['model'][$key];
     $objectToinsert['chassis_no'] = $postedData['vehicle']['chassis_no'][$key];
     so on.................
     $this->db->insert('vehicle', $postedData);

}
```

Comment: i would make it something like this : `name="vehicle[][vehicle_no]"` as it will organise the details of specific vehicle into it's own array.

Comment: ok lets say we go as name="vehicle[][vehicle_no] what would be it like the inserting to database & retveing

Comment: thanks guys, if you guys can elaborate on  how can i insert this to database that would be great

Comment: name="vehicle[][vehicle_no]" This is good. But it will cause difficulty in writing server side code.  on server side you will get something like.
$_POST[vehicle][0][vehicle_no] = "vvc";
$_POST[vehicle][1][make] = "vvc";
$_POST[vehicle][2][model] = "vvc";

Comment: @ Rakesh Kumar could you please assist me in detail like, what is the best method

Comment: For your understanding implement bot ways and check what is good, then you will understand what is happening.  If you want to go in easy way then i explained in answer.

Comment: @ Rakesh Kumar i prefer your 1st answer bu no idea how the model & control should be, never work in a large array like this before. can you provide example of model & controller

Comment: @– Rakesh Kumar please do so

Comment: @Rakesh Kumar thanks, no need to pu index for the arrays right(ex[3])

Comment: any anyone tell me why i am getting T_FOR error from the above code

Comment: @– Rakesh Kumar why is this

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Comment: @ Rakesh Kumar also prompt undefined variable for some items

Comment: Whithout looking at code i can't say why you are facing problem, i want to look at mvc.